# How to run InitState() upon back button in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

I have a two pages, in one page, i open Hive box but when I navigate to second page, the dispose() method runs and closes the Hive box. but the problem is, when i click on 'Back' button, the initState doesnt rerun on the first page, so I couldn't open the box again through initState.

here is the code on First page,

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Hive.openBox<boxModel>('customTable');
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    Hive.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Here is the **back** in appbar in second page,

```
AppBar(
      leadingWidth: 100,
       leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: AppTheme.colors.greyFontColor,
        ),
        ),
       backgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.appBarColor,
       elevation: 0,
       iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppTheme.colors.greyFontColor),)
```

so is there a way to re run to the initState upon the back button pressed on second page.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: why you open the box and close it in the lifecycle methods ?

Comment: if i dont close it, it will slow down the app, so is it true?

Comment: no, it will not, please refer to this https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/more/faq?id=do-i-have-to-call-hiveclose

Answer (score 0):

**try (context as Element).reassemble();** try this snippet refresh and build widgets again in current screen flutter.

**Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>PreviousPage() ,));** for previous using navigator.

Comment: but here is a problem. i have more than 60 pages, how can i use this for those pages? in your code, i can use this for only one page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that dispose runs when you push a new route, at least not as long as there is a back button to go back, but anyways if you just want to open the box again you can add this to your `Navigator.push`

```
Navigator.of(context)
.push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) =>  SecondPage(),
)).then((_) {
  Hive.openBox<boxModel>('customTable');
});
```

Comment: but here is a problem. i have more than 60 pages, how can i use this for those pages? in your code, i can use this for only one page. secondly, the dispose method runs when i navigate to another page. thirdly, i have more than 10 boxes for different models, so i want to open that specific box which is opened by the initState, not all boxes. this way i believe i can keep the app more performant???